# Variable in a Text String

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe-reader

I created a PDF form with PDF-Xchange.
In this PDF I want to integrate a Button that triggers the sending of an email. I create a Variable of "FullName", which consists of two fields. the “First Name ID” and the “Last Name ID”. This variable is used to sign the email.

Here is my Java script, it works fine in PDF-Xchange, different PDF Reader, but does not work in Acrobat Reader.

```
var FullName = this.getField('Prenom ID').value + ' ' + this.getField('Nom ID').value;

this.mailDoc(true, "test@gmail.com", "", "", "Fiche d'inscription ", `Mesdames, Messieurs,\r\n\r\n veuillez trouvez ci-joint ma(es) fiche(s) d'inscription, afin de m'enregistrer à votre service offet.\r\n\r\nJe vous remercie d'avance pour l'enregistrement.\r\n\r\nCordialement\r\n\r\n ${FullName}`);
```

Trying to insert in a email body a variable

Comment: I don't know the answer, but please be aware that each JavaScript (note: single word, not related to Java) runtime implements a different set of features. String templates are relatively new. If you don't control the environment, you'd better stick to good old `+` operator.

Comment: The problem is this "${FullName}" insertion of the variable.
Without the variable it works also in Adobe reader.

Answer (score 0):

I think adobe reader disables JavaScript by default. You need to enable it manually

Comment: Hi, thats right.
But i enable JS, receive an error in the console " SyntaxError: illegal character".

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with string handling switch the string to a msg alert and we see it is OK the reason it is rejected is the method in use.

[image]

Points to beware of

Fields should not contain spaces, if possible use underscore. Here I used `PreNomID` and `NomID`

Default OS emails are a thing of the past, so there problems getting submittals to work the way they did last century when the "Forms Submittal" system was designed.

There are multiple ways to trigger a submission in several formats such as send data in one of three containers via 2 different routes. Most likely to work is posting lighter weight data only to a Server as generally used by government forms.

When sending data in the background only the field contents (including any text field contents are sent), so using those methods your free format text needs to be in a field container.

So overall I tried 2 buttons the first using email system attempts to work but because I have no server to send to and will not install an email sender as "Too old hat". It fails like this without trigger the JavaScript warning shown as from the other method that presumably you tried.
**Note in Acrobat there is no way to use email it is "greyed out"**

[image]

Answer use the submittals system in Acrobat Pro via a server posting, it should not trigger a JavaScript warning as it is Adobe designed method for reader to transmit FDF from outwith a PDF.

When you say it work in other systems for you that is because your device has ben structured to work different to others. However, for me (and potentially all your clients) your method requires me to sign a string of dependencies, and as a user I do not need to sign into mail systems that way.

[image]

Comment: Hi i tried also tih Name Field Name Prenom-ID and Nom_ID, no change.
The problem is the "${FullName}" in the second line, withou the variable in the second line an using "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" it works fine, also in Adobe Reader no Error an my default Email client open a new email, prefilled.

Comment: Your sugestions are interesting, but the PDF Form is send to a customer by email, he fill it out an send it back. The form is not located at a server.
Sending email with Adobe Reader works fine , when i don't use the variable in the second line. The problem is the variable in the second line.